# st () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

not binding function with button
when I click button window closes

ERROR

```
st () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

---

```
from kivy.uix.button import  Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
class new(BoxLayout):
    def st(self):
        print("vllghh")
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bt=Button(text="njfhjgfg")
        self.add_widget(self.bt)
        self.bt.bind(on_press=self.st)
class am(App):
    def build(self):
        return new()
am().run()
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Kivy calls the `st` callback with the button instance as the only argument, but because `st` is a method of the class `new`, the 'self' parameter is implicitly passed as the first argument, making the button instance the second argument. Try changing `st` method to:

```
    def st(self, instance):
        print("vllghh")
```